# Acrobat does not execute javascript in document sent for signature

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I started noticing that pdfs with embedded javascript that used to work no longer do. The javascript executes properly in the Acrobat Pro DC app, but when I send the doc for signature, the javascript does not execute.

To test it, I created a test doc with just a couple of fields. I inserted the following javascript: app.alert('howdy');
as the validation code in one of the fields.

It works fine in the app but when I send it out for signature, it does not execute. I've spent hours chatting with Adobe agents. They repaired my installation, uninstalled it, reinstalled it, cleaned it, tried everything. Ultimately they declared that it was a javascript problem and not their responsibility.

I need help, and it doesn't appear to be forthcoming from Adobe.

Comment: I doubt we can answer your question as it certainly doesn't seem like a JavaScript problem.  Yet, even if it is,  the question doesn't include the code and debugging details needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Here's the code: app.alert('howdy'); That's the totality of it.

Comment: Are you using Acrobat Sign to send for signature? If so, the JavaScript won't run at all in that environment.

Comment: Joelgeraci: thanks for that idea. I don't think I'm using Acrobat Sign--it looks like it is a Mobile app and I'm on a PC. However you gave me the idea that perhaps my problem started after I elevated my user to admin. So I created a new user thinking they would be able to log in to acrobat.adobe.com and find my account data there. Nope, the new user isn't linked to my account. But they do have the ability to request e-signature. I tried that, but no, the javascript in the doc sent for signature still does not work. I'm really at a loss here. Certainly would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out joelgeraci was right on. An Adobe employee whom I got to know through a personal connection confirmed that when sending a pdf using acrobat.adobe.com for signature, the javascript is not sent, or is disabled. It's a huge disappointment to me, after developing a fair bit of javascript to perform field validation that cannot be done using the built-in validators. The consequence is that people will be signing a form that is invalid.